# Which approach is better to define Data Annotation (View Model or Entity )?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

### *Better approach to define Data annotation in entity or view model ?*

I have entity and view model for the same entity and override the class with Data Annotation of entity framework. 
The question is i can add them without creating a separate model however i have concern about which one better approach?

Thank you in advance.

Entity

```
[Table("BatchInfo")]
    public partial class BatchInfo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BatchInfoId { get; set; }
        public string TRANCODE { get; set; }
        public string BatchId  { get; set; }
        public bool AMTFLAG { get; set; }
        public int POS { get; set; }

    }
```

View Model

```
 [NotMapped]
    public class BatchInfoViewModel:BatchInfo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Transaction Code is required")]
        [Remote("CheckTranCode", "BatchInfo",AdditionalFields = "BatchInfoId", ErrorMessage = "Transaction Code Already Exists!")]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9^]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Transaction Code")]
        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Transaction Code Should Not be More than 3 Characters")]
        public new string TRANCODE { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Batch Code is required")]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9^]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Batch Code")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Transaction Code Should Not be More than 5 Characters")]
        public new  string BatchId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position is required")]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only Number is allowed")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Position")]
        public new  int? POS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: View models do not extend data models (they are separate classes in a separate namespace and know should have no knowledge of the data model). And you can add them in both, although a `[Remote]` males no sense in a data model

Comment: The view model pertains more to the UI while the entity ties more directly to the backend repository. Even though you will duplicate some of your entities there are plenty of advantages to having a separate object per layer. This is more evident when you get into localization, user interface validation, calculated or derived fields for display purposes and other non-backend facets.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you means we should not extend data model in view model ? What about if we do not want to override property but needs to access ? Should we create new ?

Comment: Yes, They are separate classes (in a separate folder say 'ViewModels`). Remove the `[NotMapped]` since its not appropriate, Remove the `:BatchInfo` from the class definition, and remove the `new ` new keywords (typically you copy the properties from your data model, add UI specific attributes (`[Display]`, [DisplayFormat]` etc) and additional properties needed in the view - e.g. `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for a `DropDownListFor()` method etc)

Comment: than what is use of [NotMapped] ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications

Comment: @Rahul, `[NotMapped]` is an EF attribute that you can apply to a property in a data model to instruct EF not to generate that property in the db. Its not applicable when using a view model (which you should always be using, especially when editing data)