# Its good to use [NotMapped] in side EF code first Model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

In My Case, I have a question about in my model I need one extra field like this

```
public class PassportStamp
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "BloggerName must be 10 characters or  less"), MinLength(5)]
        public string BloggerName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string BlogCode
        {
            get
            {
                return Title.Substring(0, 1) + ":" + BloggerName.Substring(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I use this way or can I create a separate view model for this field 
**and** also can I use data Data Annotations at this way or create a separate view model for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use `[NotMapped]` in your case. `[NotMapped]` is useful in those scenarios where you don't want to create a table column, but you want to use it with some custom properties.

e.g. In your model class `Student`, there are fields `FirstName` and `LastName`. If you client needs `FullName` of `Student` object. Then you can simply use `[NotMapped]` in this case. Because there is no use to create a separate column for this in the table. And you don't need to write a custom logic while using `FullName` throughout the application.

Comment: and whats about `[MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "BloggerName must be 10 characters or  less"), MinLength(5)]` its valid to use ErrorMessage in Model ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it for the model. and also you can handle it in client-side code also like using Javascript, JQuery or Angular. But just think if the user has disabled script from the browser, then you must have the serverside validation also.

Comment: you are right but you can please check this like this question comment will confusing me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857548/which-approach-is-better-to-define-data-annotation-view-model-or-entity)

Comment: The approach mentioned in the above link also works, But just think you need to change both the classes if want to add/delete/modify any property. So its all your choice.

Comment: @Jay But if suppose you want to set the datatype to `varchar(10)` in that case you  can use `MaxLength(10)]` in your model class

Comment: that's right both are correct but as per your guid which approach i use ?

Comment: **as per your guid** means?

Comment: as per your guid means as par suggestions which is better?

Comment: @Jay Again I would say, it's your choice.